# how do you compile lp_solve toward macports php 5.4.2?

Tags: php, macports, lpsolve

I followed the instructions here: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/PHP.htm#Compile_the_lpsolve_driver and downloaded the source from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/ however when I type phpize from the directory of the source I get this message: `Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/opt/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module.` I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I don't see a config.m4 anywhere (recursively) in the source directory for for lpsolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GOT IT.

I've posted the steps below I took to get it working. It looks long but it's not that bad.

These three sites were helpful in solving the issue.

[For building the correct library](http://diegoresearch.wordpress.com/2008/07/10/using-lp_solve-in-java-with-mac-os-x/)

[For malloc error when using make](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/node/694)

[For function_entry error when using make](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61479)

Download:
`lp_solve_5.5.2.0_source.tar`,
`lp_solve_5.5.2.0_PHP_source.tar`

From http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/files/lpsolve/5.5.2.0/

These are the steps I took to get it working. First make sure your extensions directory is correct. I set mine back to the default (basically commenting it back out making it `/opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525`) in the `php.ini` file. I also added the line `extension=phplpsolve55.so`. Use `$ port unload apache2` and `$ port load apache2` to restart the webserver.

At this point in your terminal if you run `$ php` it should complain about not being able to find the `phplpsolve55.so` driver.

Download and expand `lp_solve_5.5_source.tar.gz` into a
directory named `lp_solve_5.5`.

Download and expand `lp_solve_5.5.2.0_PHP_source.tar` into a
directory named `lp_solve_5.5_PHP`.

**1) Build the lp_solve library in the source directory.**

```
$ cd lp_solve_5.5/lpsolve55
$ sh ccc.osx
```

This creates two new files in the lpsolve55 subdirectory:

```
$ ls liblp*
liblpsolve55.a     liblpsolve55.dylib
```

For me the two files were located in `lpsolve55\bin\osx64`

**2) Install the lp_solve library.**

If not already in directory `lpsolve55`, cd to it.  Copy `liblpsolve55.a` and `liblpsolve55.dylib` to `/usr/local/lib` (you may need to create `/usr/local/lib` first: `$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib`):

```
$ sudo cp liblpsolve55.a liblpsolve55.dylib /usr/local/lib
```

**3) Test the build and installation.**

```
$ cd lp_solve_5.5/demo
```

The `ccc.osx` script is broken.  The good news is that version 5.5 of
lp_solve fixes the "malloc.h" incompatibility on the Mac that was in
earlier versions.  The Unix/Linux script now works on OS X.  Be
patient...
it may take several seconds to build 'demo':

```
$ sh ccc
```

The example problems in the demo should issue no errors and have
"Excellent numeric accuracy ||*|| = 0":

```
$ ./demo
```

**3) Build the php lpsolve library**

Now go into the PHP directory (`lp_solve_5.5_PHP`)

```
$ cd lp_solve_5.5_PHP/extra/PHP
$ phpize
$ ./configure --enable-maintainer-zts --with-phplpsolve55=PATH TO SOURCE DIRECTORY
```

*Where PATH TO SOURCE DIRECTORY is wherever you put the lp_solve_5.5*

Then open `PHPmod.c` which should be in the current (`lp_solve_5.5_PHP/extra/PHP`) directory and change `function_entry` to `zend_function_entry`

Then open `hash.c` which should also be in the same directory and change the line that says

```
#include <malloc.h>
```

to

```
#if !defined(__APPLE__)
#include <malloc.h>
#endif
```

** *note I only know to do this because I ran `$ make` on my machine before doing this and it complained about these two files**

then do

```
$ make
$ cd modules
$ sudo cp phplpsolve55.so /opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/
```

Now running `$ php` shouldn't return any errors.

Restart the apache server again and the extension should work. If not I'll help as much as I can.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

***EDIT***

Just updated to Mavericks and everything works perfectly fine still. What I did was follow the steps outlined [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration), ran `$ xcode-select --install` after finishing the upgrade. Then I did `$ sudo port selfupdate` and finally ran the script at the bottom of the page to reload all my ports:

```
curl -O https://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/contrib/restore_ports/restore_ports.tcl
chmod +x restore_ports.tcl
sudo ./restore_ports.tcl myports.txt
```

Once that was done I did a `$ sudo port load apache2` and everything still worked.

Comment: I had to copy the /extra directory into the source directory. See PHP Module Installation, Step 1 from http://jeyroz.tumblr.com/post/605709794/lpsolve-php  Anyhow: thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Look in `lp_solve_5.5/extra/PHP/` to see if you are able to find `config.m4` there.

This [nabble thread](http://lp-solve.2324885.n4.nabble.com/Version-for-PHP-with-integrated-library-td5458.html) is dated, but it should be of help.

Comment: Okay I used this thread: http://lp-solve.2324885.n4.nabble.com/installing-lpsolve-with-python-2-6-td8728.html to help and now I get this issue: configure: error: Invalid phplpsolve55 library, make_lp() not found